# Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-core'

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I try to connect AWS DynamoDB with ElasticSearch. I follow that instructon:

https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb

However I hit the problem. I got an error calling that code:

```
jruby -S gem install --local logstash-input-dynamodb-1.0.0-java.gem
```

Error:

[image]

And my DynamoDB file:

[image]

Comment: What's the version of your logstash?

Answer (score 3):

I installed https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb on Linux successfully.

I followed the steps till:

```
jruby -S gem build logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec
```

which generated **"logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec"** file

logstash-core was installed in this folder:

**$ /jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/logstash-core-2.0.0.rc1-java**

Than I updated the **"logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec"** file (generated above) with the following:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "logstash-core", '~> 2.0.0rc1', '< 3.0.0'
```

Again i did a build:

```
jruby -S gem build logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec
```

which generated **logstash-input-dynamodb-1.0.0-java.gem**

After running this command:

```
jruby -S gem install --local logstash-input-dynamodb-1.0.0-java.gem
```

it successfully got installed under:
**$ /jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems** folder

Next Steps:

1. I installed logstash 2.4.1
2. in the Gemfile i added: `gem "logstash-input-dynamodb"`
3. bin/plugin install --no-verify logstash-input-dynamodb
4. bin/plugin list  - shows that logstash-input-dynamodb is installed